# Не работает перевод для множественного числа на некоторых языках

Tags: php, yii2, multilanguage, icu

можно ли заставить Yii2 переводить множественные формы слов для некоторых языков (для некоторых потому что например для EN и RU все хорошо работает)?
**Как использую:**

```
//хранится в messages/ru/site.php
'cats' => '{count, plural, one{кот} few{кота} many{котов} other{котов}}' 

 //использование
Yii::t('site', 'cats', ['count' => 702])
```

**Ниже привожу примеры что работает и не работает:**

этот пример хорошо срабатывает для RU:

```
'cats' => '{count, plural, one{кот} few{кота} many{котов} other{котов}}'
```

пример ниже для UA независимо от числа срабатывает только часть `other{котів}` все остальные игноряться:

```
'cats' => '{count, plural, one{кіт} few{коти} many{котів} other{котів}}'
```

для UA сделал еще так и сработало для чисел от 1-4 но к примеру если будет число 92 - то выведет "**92 котів**" а не кота:

```
'cats' => ' {count, plural, =1{кіт} =2{коти} =3{коти} =4{коти} few{коти} many{котів} other{котів}}'
```

Подскажите как можно решить данную проблему, что бы срабатывало для всех чисел?

**Версии:**

```
PHP: 7.0.21 
ICU: 57.1
```